# set y-axis range to be +/-10 percentage points of data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I am plotting multiple (~300) bar graphs and would like to fix the y-axis range at between +/- 10 percentage points of data in my dataset. Eg: if the y-axis range in my data set is (10,20), I'd like to display the graph rage as (0,30). Any idea how to do this easily across all plots? Thanks

Comment: do you mean 0, 30?

Comment: See [`?expansion`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expansion.html).

Comment: I'm not sure how `[10,20]` maps to `[0,30]` with 10% of anything. If my note on `expansion` doesn't work, please provide a reproducible example with sample data and minimal plotting code. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, you're looking to expand the y axis by +/- 10 *percent*; however, inside the text of your question it seems you need to expand by +/- 10 *units* (whatever your units of the y axis happen to be).  You can do either quite easily using `expansion()`, which can be applied to `scale_y_continuous()` via the `expand =` argument.  Here's an example plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:4], y=c(10, 20, 30, 25))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_col()
```

The limits of the data in `y` are `[10, 30]` as stated in your question.  If you want to automatically expand those by 10 units in either direction, you need to apply `expansion(add = (...))` to the `expand=` argument in `scale_y_continuous()`.  In the [documentation for that function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expansion.html), you'll see that if you supply a vector of length 1 to `add=`, it will be applied to both upper and lower limits, whereas you can specify how to expand lower and upper limits individually if you supply a vector with length of 2.  So for example, to expand by 10 units outward for both, you just use `add=10`:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = 10))
```

[image]

If you want to keep the lower limit the same and only add to the y axis (by `15` in this case), you specify a vector with 2 numbers:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0,15)))
```

[image]

If you want to expand by a *percentage*, you can specify `mult=` instead of `add=`.  This takes the number or numbers assigned to `mult=` and multiples that by the highest or lowest value in your plot.  So, to expand by 10% in either direction, you multiply by 0.1:

```
p + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Super helpful, exactly what I was looking for. Ended up using scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(add = c(0,15)))